Solving the system $xy = 15$, $x + y - \sqrt {\frac{{x + y}}{{x - y}}} = \frac{{12}}{{x - y}}$
The system is:
$$\begin{align}
x + y - \sqrt {\frac{{x + y}}{{x - y}}}  &= \frac{{12}}{{x - y}}\\[4pt]
xy &= 15
\end{align}$$
I've tried making the following substitutions: $t = x + y,u = x - y$, but to no avail.
I only get that $xy = {{{t^2} - {u^2}} \over 4} \Rightarrow {t^2} - {u^2} = 60$
Any suggestions?

$tu-\sqrt{tu}=12$

If I solve that with a substitution of $v = \sqrt {tu}$ I get that v=-3 or v=4. Is that useful?


$$\begin{align}
x + y - \sqrt {\frac{{x + y}}{{x - y}}}  &= \frac{{12}}{{x - y}}\\[4pt]
xy &= 15
\end{align}$$

I am assuming that this is a problem in real analysis, rather than complex analysis.  Therefore any expression of the form $~k^2~$ must be non-negative.  Further, the occurrence of any expression of the form $~\displaystyle \sqrt{k}~$ indicates that $~k~$ is non-negative.
If you multiply both sides by $~(x - y)~$ you get
$$(x^2 - y^2) - \sqrt{x^2 - y^2} = 12.$$
This is a quadratic equation in the variable
$$u = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2} \implies u^2 - u - 12 = 0 \implies $$
$$u \in \{4,-3\} \implies u = 4,$$
since $~u~$ can't be negative.
Therefore, the problem has been reduced to solving the system:

$~xy = 15 \implies x^2y^2 = 225.$

$~x^2 - y^2 = u^2 = 16.$


Therefore,
$$x^2 - \left[ ~\frac{225}{x^2} ~\right] = 16 \implies $$
$$x^4 - 16x^2 - 225 = 0.$$
This is a quadratic equation in $~x^2.$
So,
$$x^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~16 \pm \sqrt{ ~16^2 + 4(225) ~} ~\right].$$
Since $~x^2~$ can not be negative, this implies that
$$x^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~16 + \sqrt{ ~16^2 + 4(225) ~} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~16 + 34 ~\right] = 25. \tag1 $$
Therefore, there are two candidate values for $~x,~$ namely
$$\{ ~-5, ~+5 ~\}. \tag2 $$
What this signifies is that while $~-5~$ or $~+5~$ each may or may not solve the problem, no other solution is possible.
So, to complete the problem, each of the candidate values must be manually checked.
Note
I think that further explanation is warranted here.  The analysis so far merely indicates that if $~x~$ satisfies the original constraints, then $~x~$ must be an element in $~\{ ~-5, +5 ~\}.~$
So far, there has been no analysis that the implication runs in the opposite direction.  So, just because $~x~$ is a specific element in $~\{ ~-5, +5 ~\}~$ does not imply that $~x~$ satisfies the original constraints.

$$x = -5 \implies y = -3 \implies \dfrac{12}{x-y} = -6.$$
Further,
$$(x + y) - \sqrt{ ~\frac{x + y}{x - y} ~} = -8 - \sqrt{ ~\frac{-8}{-2} ~} = -8 - 2 = -10.$$
Therefore, $~(x,y) = (-5,-3)~$ does not satisfy the original constraints.

$$x = 5 \implies y = 3 \implies \dfrac{12}{x-y} = 6.$$
Further,
$$(x + y) - \sqrt{ ~\frac{x + y}{x - y} ~} = 8 - \sqrt{ ~\frac{8}{2} ~} = 8 - 2 = 6.$$
Therefore, $~(x,y) = (5,3)~$ satisfies the original constraints.

As an alternative to using the Quadratic Formula, observe that \begin{align*} x^4 - 16x^2 - 225 & = x^4 - 25x^2 + 9x^2 - 225\ & = x^2(x^2 - 25) + 9(x^2 - 25)\ & = (x^2 + 9)(x^2 - 25)\ & = (x^2 + 9)(x + 5)(x - 5)\end{align*}

First of all, $x+y,x-y$ should have the same sign $\ \ \ \ (0)$,
else $\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}<0$
We have $$12=(x+y)(x-y)-(x-y)\sqrt{\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}}$$
Case $\#1:$ If $x-y>0\ \ \ \ (1),$
$$ (\sqrt{x^2-y^2})^2-\sqrt{x^2-y^2}=12$$
If $\sqrt{x^2-y^2}=u\ge0$ for real $x^2-y^2,12=u^2-u\implies u=4$
Let $\sqrt{\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}}=t\ge0\ \ \ \  (2)$
$\implies\dfrac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}=\dfrac xy$
But $xy=15\implies x^2=\dfrac xy\cdot xy=\dfrac{15(t^2+1)}{t^2-1}\ \ \ \ (3)$
Similarly, $y^2=\dfrac{15(t^2-1)}{t^2+1}\ \ \ \ (4)$
$\implies x^2-y^2=\dfrac{15(t^2+1)}{t^2-1}-\dfrac{15(t^2-1)}{t^2+1}=\dfrac{15(4t^2)}{t^4-1}$ which is $=u^2=4^2$
$$\implies0=4t^4-15t^2-4=(4t^2+1)(t^2-4)\implies t=2\text{ by }(2)$$
Utilize $(3),(4)$ to find $x^2,y^2$ hence the values of $x,y$ which satisfy $(1)$
Case $\#2:$ If $x-y<0\ \ \ \ (5)\iff x+y<0 $ by $(0)$
Let $x=-a, y=-b$
$$\implies12=-(b+a)(b-a)-(b-a)\sqrt{\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}}$$
$$\iff(b^2-a^2)+\sqrt{b^2-a^2}-12=0\implies b^2-a^2=3$$
I leave the rest as an exercise.
